# Blackboard アーキテクチャの実装例（OSS など）をどこかで見れないか

Tags: データ構造, 情報理論

こんばんは。

題名の通りなのですが、Blackboard アーキテクチャで実装された何らかのシステムのソースを見る事はできないでしょうか。

アーキテクチャについて興味があり色々調べているのですが、文章で見ても「ふむふむ、まぁそんなもんか」という程度で、実装レベルで実感が湧きません。

どなたかリポジトリの URL などお教え頂けると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1):

よくわかりませんがSourceForgeを検索すると色々ヒットしました。

http://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/?q=blackboard+

これ↓とかそれっぽいので試して見てはいかがでしょう。

> OpenBBS is an open and extensible blackboard system for the development of flexible workflows. The flexibility is achieved through adoption of the blackboard pattern. OpenBBS is modular and embeddable which makes it a lightwheight solution for workflows.

http://openbbs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: なるほどそういう手がありましたね！

openbbs 見てみます。ありがとうございます。